# Find the number using the data

Tags: steganography

There is a number hidden in this picture

[image: 36*8/12]

The number is not 365

This is all I can tell you for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is:

> 24 (Original guess: 1)

Explanation:

> The math expression of the picture (could be seen in edit mode) is 36*8/12, making 24.
> (Original guess: "**First** blank page" and the simple instruction: "Write a good **one**".)

Comment: Well tried but rot13(gur nafjre vf uvqqra VA gur cvpgher abg BA vg)

Comment: Well done .... I think my hint gave away the answer by the way, how did you have the idea to go into edit mode

Comment: I am nosy enough to go into the edit mode of each question I am interested in, like this LOL ★ and +1!