# Guess the puzzle

Tags: steganography

This is the answer
Find the puzzle


Note:This is a legitimate question so please don't downvote it

Comment: If it wasn't marked with steganography tag, my answer would have been: rot13 "Fb ntnva, jung jnf lbhe evqqyr"

Comment: Hmmm... but here the answer is hidden

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at

> The edit history, the second edit description says ‘the riddle is "find 2*3"’

So the answer is

> 6.

Comment: I believe that this is the correct answer, well done!

Comment: So similar to this though XD https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75285/find-the-number-using-the-data/75287#75287

Comment: @OmegaKrypton that is also one of my questions

Comment: Oh yah @Quark-epoch

Answer (score 8):

Deciphering with the isle-eyed Itzmey-Dupp cipher, we get

> Short is the pronoun
>  Rhymes with miss

Which makes sense, since according to the description

> "this" is the answer.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here, but as I haven't ever heard of "isle-eyed Itzmey-Dupp cipher", nor does Google know anything about it, I think I'll risk the question: what is this?

Comment: @zovits if you say it out loud you get.....

Comment: but what about the stenography tag?

Comment: @El-Guest If I say it out loud, I get at most strange stares from my co-workers :D But seriously, I still don't get it...

Comment: "I lied.  It's my dupe cipher"

Comment: I actually thought it was “I lied, it’s made up” cipher.... but that’s a good one too, @BenBarden!