# Find the puzzle #2

Tags: steganography

[View the first part here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75864/guess-the-puzzle)

This is the solution

 
Find the puzzle

P.S:This puzzle is a ***little*** different from the last one
This is completely legitimate so please don't downvote it

**Hint 1**

> 90% of you have already seen the answer

**Note**

> " ***This***" is not the answer

**Hint 2**

> Look at find the puzzle part 1

**Hint 3**

> You have to find the ***Puzzle***

Comment: ROT13: qbrf pbzchgrevpny.zy tvivat 403/500 unir nalguvat gb qb jvgu gur chmmyr?

Comment: Alternative theory: ROT13: "cerfragnoyr"?

Comment: @ace no but the second one is close

Comment: This one's clearly encrypted with the Allsough-Bowguss...

Comment: No it is not encrypted it is HIDDEN

Comment: I'm gonna take another guess: `<br>`

Comment: @ace if you think you have the answer, please post as an answer response below instead of as a comment on the question.

Comment: @Dorrulf i know, but it feels a bit too stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on hint 3:

> Are you talking about the word *puzzle* in the explanation of revision 2 for this puzzle: "Added a 
>  tag to make the **puzzle** presentable" ?
>  (Would be similar to how you hid the riddle/puzzle in guess the puzzle #1, albeit a bit more literal...)

---

Based on hint 2:

> As @El-Guest answered in [*Guess* the puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75864/guess-the-puzzle), [Rev. 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/75864/2) has a hidden question asking for 2*3, which is **6**

More attempts because why not:

The post discovery forehead smacker:

> How do I/you make this puzzle presentable?
>  Add a `<br />`

Note:

> If that really is the answer, then credits primarily to @ace. If they make an answer post, then it should go to them.

The sillier wild attempt #3:

> The first edit also affects the word 'here' and discusses a break tag.
>  So, "I need a break from here", which can't possibly be true! :P

---

Wild attempt #2:

> I don't see much provided here in the question, so I'm back to looking at your profile. Somehow, you have 9 other SE "accounts" that are all at 101 rep points. Dunno how you pulled that off, but it makes me think this question has something to do with that. Thus my guess is this:
>  101 * 9 = 909

---

Wild attempt:
Answer is

> Gas

Thoughts:

> In your profile, there is the hint "Check the state of matter of the poison".
>  In the first part, the answer is 6.
>  6 on the periodic table is carbon, and carbon monoxide is a know issue in homes. It is also a gas.

In counter:

> 1. There may not be enough edits yet so I could be missing something.
>  2. What really gets me is the break tag. So I wouldn't be surprised if my current answer is incorrect.

Comment: That was for another question. I will remove it . Thanks for reminding

Comment: The 101 rep is due to the association bonus. If your account has 200 rep and you link it to another site you get a 100 rep added on to your account on that site giving you a net of 101. This is meant to be a way to allow experienced users on one SE platform to have some privileges on others as they already know the basics of the site.

Comment: Oh. Alright, good to know thanks @gabbo1092

Comment: @Quark-epoch If it was for another question, that other question should be deleted since it is no longer solvable. This is exactly why questions using profiles are discouraged: you have now made a question impossible to solve, with no indication. Puzzling is supposed to be an archive of quality puzzles that can be solved at *any time*; you've broken a puzzle by editing your profile.

Comment: it is not related to my profile

Comment: @Quark-epoch Deusovi means your previous question that you earlier said 'that was for another question. I will remove it.' . If you made a question that uses your profile to solve and then you change that part of your profile that question is now useless on this site.

Comment: No, that was a hint it is still solvable @gabbo1092

Comment: No, that was a hint it is still solvable  @Deusovi ♦

Answer (score 3):

The puzzle is

> What English word, that is an adverb,
> an adjective and/or a determiner
> (depending on which dictionary you consult),
> and a pronoun, can you form
> with the letters `I`, `H`, `S` and `T`
> (using each one exactly once)?
> <sub>(Get your minds out of the gutter!)</sub>

And ...

> ***This***

... is the solution.

Comment: I would never have such a straightforward solution but still well tried

Comment: $#!+ this was a good answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with

> **#** (the number sign)

because

> when you XOR the riddle with the title you get "this is the solution #2," or rearranged, "# is the solution 2 (to) this."

Hint:

> A bit of trickiness, 90% of you have already seen the answer refers to the OP guessing about 90% of people will read the spoiler, thus seeing the words 'the answer' in the spoiler. Alternatively, a guess 90% of people know about XOR.

Comment: That is way too complicated. My riddles are not very simple but also not SOOO complicated. Well tried +1

Answer (score 1):

Is the puzzle..

> Presentable? ("make the puzzle presentable" in the edits)

Also credits to @ace because he spotted it first.

2nd attempt:

Is it...

> The html code? I found a "Hi..." hidden there, couldn't find any other hidden things. That being said, "Hi..." could be the solution itself.

Comment: No but you may or may not be close

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if This is correct but I guess

> **This** is, indeed, the solution
>  [image]

Comment: It is HIDDEN. Definitely I would not have such a straightforward answer but still, well tried